# Calling methods on React DOM elements from outside of the React class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have injected a React element into my DOM using `ReactDOM.render` -- e.g.:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How can I call methods on the `<App/>` instance directly from outside of the `App` class?

In particular, I'd like to perform the equivalent of `this.setState(...)` where `this` is set to the `App` element and force it to be re-rendered.

Comment: Hmmm why tho ? whats the use case.

Comment: passing a new prop to `App` will trigger a new render

Comment: @Sag1v Do you mean just call `ReactDom.render(<App s={...}/>, document.getElementById('root'))` with a different value for `...`? Will this do a diff and patch or discard what's already at `root` and replace it?

Comment: @ErikR Why would you want to do such a thing when your ```App```  component will re-render anyways upon receiving changed props?

Comment: calling ReactDOM.render multiple times has the same effect as calling setState on App https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/691301224541503488?lang=en

Comment: @m-ketan Can you give an example of "receiving changed props"? I'm not a React expert!

Comment: I'm not sure what @m-ketan is saying. the only way to "pass new props" to the root component is by calling ReactDOM.render again